# Is it ok to ask about next contract terms?

Tags: contracts, italy

In 2 weeks my contract as an intern will expire, and the company has already expressed their will of keeping me.

I have already been informed about the next contract they will offer me, but very briefly, threfore I'd like to get more information about it (such as duration, weekly hours, if I am expected to do overtime...) before it is in front of me and my only choice will be either sign it or not.

My question is: is it ok to ask about this information? Or am I expected to not know it until the very last day?

This is my very first job experience so I'm sorry if my question has an obvious answer.

Comment: Will you still be an intern, or are they hiring you as a regular employee?

Comment: @Erik I will be hired as a regular employee

Answer (score 5):

Not only is it okay for you to ask, you should have already seen this. A contract is a negotiation between two parties, who both have their own wishes and demands regarding an acceptable contract.

You really should have a look, because if you wait until the last minute and they provide you an offer you don't want to take, you'll be unemployed. And you'll be in a bad negotiating position if they tell that if you don't sign now, you won't be able to come in to work tomorrow.

You should take at least a few days time to read the contract, and think about if it's what you want to sign, and what your alternatives are. Unless you absolutely trust your current employer to give you a great deal, you probably want to have a look around and see what other companies are available in your area and what they offer.

(Especially if you don't even know basic things like "how many hours a week will I work"! That will have a huge impact on what you'll be doing in the upcoming months and whether you'll be able to afford life.)

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.